# SSRS Matrix filter value operator IN not acting correctly

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS's Matrix, I entered the filter value like this:

[image: Entered Values like this]

Then it ends up like this:

[image: End up with this]

It works for other matrix, but just this one is acting weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your expression: type in

```
"APACC", "APBATT, "APCHG", "APLB"
```